# formula to calculate aspect ratio with smallest possible integer numerator and denominator

Tags: math, formula, aspect-ratio

I want to get the aspect ratio of files (like images or videos | `width` and `height` are known as well) expressed in smallest possible `integer` values (whole numbers).

Lets say the file has a `width = 300px` and a `height = 100px` so the aspect ratio is `3 / 1`.

But what if we have a `width = 300px` and a `height = 250px`? The aspect ratio is `1.2 / 1`. But like I said before I want to have both the `numerator` and `denominator` as smallest possible `integer` values which would be `6 / 5` in this particular case.

Is there a **formula to calculate this** straight forward or do I have to do it programmatically?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what language you are using, but if you have access to a math library with gcd (greatest common divisor), it would be something like

```
int gcd = gcd(width, height);
int numerator = width / gcd;
int denominator = height / gcd;
```